# Next logical move in Heyawake

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

I'm just starting out on Heyawake.  On this puzzle, I didn't see the next logical move, so I tried the 3 box with LRL and then RLR and I didn't have any luck going down those bifurcations.  What am I supposed to see here?
[image: place i am stuck]

This is 8x8 Normal Heyawake nr [4,890,742](https://www.puzzle-heyawake.com/?pl=179c22e606bac3340fac592bc64f740f64717c42e1ec9) at puzzle-heyawake.com.

Answer (score 7):

> You have two white cells in the bottom right corner that are closed on three sides (either by black cells or the border of the grid). Since all white cells must form one continuous area, both of those cells must be bordered by a white cell and in both cases there's only one option where that can be. So row 6 column 8 and row 8 column 6 must both be white.

Comment: Thanks.  From there, I see the rest.  Sheesh.  Sorry for being such a newb.  I only started playing this a few days ago, and I'm still getting the basics.  I appreciate the answer!  Steve

Comment: @Steve Welcome to Puzzling! If you found this answer helpful, please consider clicking the checkmark to Accept it as the answer to your question. :)